# Странное поведение примитивных функций при работе с широкими символами

Tags: c, mingw, mingw-w64

Использую MinGW-W64. В нём нет err.h Раньше мне хватало нагугленного суррогата в виде

```
void warn(const char* msg, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, msg);

    vfprintf(stderr, msg, args);

    va_end(args);
}

void err(int status, const char* msg, ...) {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, msg);

    warn(msg, args);

    va_end(args);
    exit(status);
}
```

Но сегодня я столкнулся со странным поведением этих функций при работе с широкими строками. Если вызвать так

```
warn("%ws\n", L"Привет");
```

В консоль будет выведено приветствие. Но если так

```
err(EXIT_FAILURE, "%ws\n", L"Привет");
```

То не будет выведено ничего. Почему? Ведь `err` - просто обёртка вокруг `warn`. И она успешно справляется со своей работой, в случае пары аргументов `"%s"` и `"Hello"`.

**Обновление:** Проблема распространяется и на использование спецификатора формата `%ls`.

Comment: У меня в консоль ничего не выводится даже при использовании `warn("%ws\n", L"Привет");`, `vfprintf` возвращает -1, `errno` `EILSEQ` (что неудивительно). Используйте `vfwprintf`

Comment: @VTT я пробовал использовать `vfwprintf` вместо `vfprintf`. При использовании `warn` всё так же нормально работает. При использовании `err` в консоль выводится символ "@"